# Single backslash in JSON serialized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I need to send string in format using MVC Json serialization

```
"America\/New_York"
```

But when I create string

```
string timezone = @"America\/New_York";

return JSON(new { timezone = timezone })
```

In the result I get:

```
{ "timezone":"America\\/New_York" }
```

How can I do it?

Edited.
If I write `@"America\/New_York"`; I will get error "Unrecognized escape sequence"
If I write `@"America/New_York";` I will get `"timezone":"America/New_York"`

Comment: `{ "timezone":"America\\/New_York" }` is the JSON serialization for a key of `timezone` and value of `America\/New_York`.  There is no need to change anything.

Comment: I worked with another languages services. So he need string in this format "America\/New_York"

Comment: I think you are not understanding me.  In javascript, the string "America\\/New_York" only has a single backslash in it.

Comment: I now it. But I work with service, not javascript. And Service require string in this format...

Comment: That's not JSON then, so you may have to create your own serializer, because the JSON serializer is going to output valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same, the JSON serializer is just adding an escape character. If you were to deserialize that into an object, call it obj, then do;

```
   Console.WriteLine(obj.timezone);
   //outputs "America\/New_York"
```

The same would be true with whatever you use to display it in the view.

In C# the @ before a string literal is a precompiler directive to not use escape characters. If you remove that @ then you would also have to write `"America\\/New_York"` in order to produce the output `"America\/New_York"`.

To clarify further;

```
 string a = @"America\/New_York";
 string b = "America\\/New_York";

 a == b //true

 string c = "America\/New_York"; //compiler error because \/ 
 // is not a recognized escape sequence
```

list of valid escape sequences (for things like tabs and new lines):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

more info on using @ for string literals:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: If I write "America\/New_York" I will get error "Unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: @IvanKorytin yes, that's because `\\`` is the escape character in string literals and the following character `/` is not part of any escape sequence. If you did `\n` or `\t` it would understand it, however, if you did `@"America\n/New_York"` you would not get a new line. The `\n` would show up in the string. If instead you removed the @ you would get `America //new line /New_York`